# Sent mail based on time that previous mail was sent

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a script that checks if a site is online and sends a mail if it's down. 
The script is configured with a scheduled task that runs every 30 minutes.

The problem is the following:

If the site is down during the weekend or evening (or a day when i'm not monitoring the mailbox), the mails keep being sent.

I was wondering, what method could I use to only send mails if the last time a mail was sent was 3 hours before?

Based on this way, i can send a mail only once every 3 hours.

I have researched the use of registry keys but was wondering if this would be the correct approach.

Comment: Why don't you modify the scheduled task during the weekends to send from 3 to another 3 hours?

Comment: since there will be time spans in which the monitoring will not be ran

Comment: Isn't that what you want? Or you want to be sent from 3 to another 3 hours just in case you see the email and don't put the server up again.

Comment: no, your answer makes it that the script runs only every 3 hours but this means that it's not monitored every 3 hours. i want to send the mail once every 3 repetitive hours.

Comment: you can also record the last run timestamp into environment variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than the registry, I'd use a simple configuraiton file stored in ProgramData (or AppData should you need a per user configuration)

This make the process of loading / saving parameters and adding new ones very easy. 
Also, should you need to save logs and / or other data, you can just put them inside that same folder.

```
$ConfigFullPath = "$env:APPDATA\My Monitoring solution\config.json"

# This create the config file if none is present. 
if (-not (Test-Path  $ConfigFullPath))  {
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $ConfigFullPath -Value ([PSCustomObject]@{'LastEmailSent' = [datetime]::MinValue}| ConvertTo-Json) -Force
}


$ConfigFileParams = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject (get-content "$env:APPDATA\My Monitoring solution\config.json" -raw)

$SendEmail = ([Datetime]::UtcNow - ([DateTime]$ConfigFileParams.LastEmailSent)).TotalHours -ge 3


if ($SendEmail) {

    try {
        # Send-MailMessage  -ErrorAction Stop
        # Once email is sent, we update the config
        $ConfigFileParams.LastEmailSent = [DateTime]::UtcNow
        $ConfigFileParams | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $ConfigFullPath
    }
    Catch {
        #Manage what to do in case of failure
    }

}
```

That being said, you can definitely use the registry to do the same. 
For convenience and ease of use though, I strongly suggest a simpler json file based approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option would be to write the starting hour in a file saved on the disk and everytime you run the script to test if

`(currentHour-hourFirstSent)%3==0 && currentMinute<30`

You put the name of the file  `yyyy-mm-dd` and if that file exist you read the starting hour from it, if not you create it and save the starting hour in it.